# Kubernetes and Wildcard DNS records

Tags: kubernetes, artifactory

Is it possible to setup my ingress with a wildcard so I can fetch images with `repositoryname.hostname` where repositoryname is the wildcard?

I have Artifactory running on my k8s cluster. To download a remote repository in Artifactory 6.x one has to type the following:

`http://<host>:<port>/artifactory/<remote-repository-name>/<artifact-path>`

Is there any way I can prefix `<remote-repository-name>` behind `<host>` so that the address would be:

`http://<remote-repository-name>.<host>:<port>/artifactory/<artifact-path>`

or

`http://<artifact-path><remote-repository-name>.<host>:<port>/artifactory`

I searched everywhere in the Artifactory docs for some kind of wildcard DNS record (or subdomain). Only thing I could find was something about docker and reverse proxies, at my work though, we'd like to be able to pull any kind of repository this way.

Comment: its mentioned here. Only single label wildcards are supported. Not sure if you could to `*.*.foo.com` though. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#hostname-wildcards

Answer (score 0):

Artifactory supports sub-domain access method, which can be setup in the Admin > Artifactory > HTTP Settings. More on this you can find [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/HTTP+Settings).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).